# Card Column Count not exceeding 6 columns

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to have multiple cards next to each other (preferebly 10), but the webpage only shows 6 at most.

Here is the css:

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  /* line 256, node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_card.scss */
  .card-columns2 {
    -webkit-column-count: 7;
            column-count: 7;
    -moz-column-count: 7;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.25rem;
            column-gap: 1.25rem;
    -moz-column-count: 1.25rem;
    width: 100%;
    orphans: 1;
    widows: 1;}
    /* line 267, node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_card.scss */
    .card-columns2 .card {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      } }
```

And here is the snippet of the HTML code:

```
<div class="mb-4 container-fluid" >
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="card-columns2">
            <div class="card card-pin">
                <img class="card-img"  src="https://snipp" alt="#1481">
                <div class="text-block" >                   
                </div>
                <div class="overlay">
                    <h2 class="card-title title"></h2>
                    <div class="more">
                        <a href="post.html">
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> More </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card card-pin">
                <img class="card-img"  src="snipp" alt="#1546">
                <div class="text-block" >           
                </div>
                <div class="overlay">
                    <h2 class="card-title title"></h2>
                    <div class="more">
                        <a href="post.html">
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> More </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And that's how it looks like with column count of 7:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hixCN.png)

It looks the same for the count of 10, but with smaller boxes.

Comment: I can't say as to why, but if you have a number divisible by seven of the class "card card-pin" you will have seven columns. At a count of 16, it gave me 6 columns, with 1 row of 6 and 2 rows of 5. The use of `column-count` for splitting content is generally used more for things like text. I suggest using either `flex-box` or `grid` to control the layout of images. `column-count` is focused on even disbursement, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  /* line 256, node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_card.scss */
  .card-columns2 {
    -webkit-column-count: 10;
            column-count: 10;
    -moz-column-count: 10;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.25rem;
            column-gap: 1.25rem;
    -moz-column-count: 1.25rem;
    width: 100%;
    orphans: 1;
    widows: 1;}
    /* line 267, node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_card.scss */
    .card-columns2 .card {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0 15px;
      } }
```

```html
<div class="mb-4 container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card-columns2">
      <div class="card card-pin">
        <img class="card-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.jpg?text=irtiza" alt="#1481">
        <div class="text-block">
        </div>
        <div class="overlay">
          <h2 class="card-title title"></h2>
          <div class="more">
            <a href="post.html">
              <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> More </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card card-pin">
        <img class="card-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.jpg?text=irtiza" alt="#1546">
        <div class="text-block">
        </div>
        <div class="overlay">
          <h2 class="card-title title"></h2>
          <div class="more">
            <a href="post.html">
              <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> More </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div
      </div>
      <div class="card card-pin">
        <img class="card-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.jpg?text=irtiza" alt="#1546">
        <div class="text-block">
        </div>
        <div class="overlay">
          <h2 class="card-title title"></h2>
          <div class="more">
            <a href="post.html">
              <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> More </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card card-pin">
        <img class="card-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.jpg?text=irtiza" alt="#1481">
        <div class="text-block">
        </div>
        <div class="overlay">
          <h2 class="card-title title"></h2>
          <div class="more">
            <a href="post.html">
              <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> More </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card card-pin">
        <img class="card-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.jpg?text=irtiza" alt="#1546">
        <div class="text-block">
        </div>
        <div class="overlay">
          <h2 class="card-title title"></h2>
          <div class="more">
            <a href="post.html">
              <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> More </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     <div class="card card-pin">
        <img class="card-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.jpg?text=irtiza" alt="#1481">
        <div class="text-block">
        </div>
        <div class="overlay">
          <h2 class="card-title title"></h2>
          <div class="more">
            <a href="post.html">
              <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> More </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card card-pin">
        <img class="card-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.jpg?text=irtiza" alt="#1546">
        <div class="text-block">
        </div>
        <div class="overlay">
          <h2 class="card-title title"></h2>
          <div class="more">
            <a href="post.html">
              <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> More </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card card-pin">
        <img class="card-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.jpg?text=irtiza" alt="#1481">
        <div class="text-block">
        </div>
        <div class="overlay">
          <h2 class="card-title title"></h2>
          <div class="more">
            <a href="post.html">
              <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> More </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card card-pin">
        <img class="card-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.jpg?text=irtiza" alt="#1546">
        <div class="text-block">
        </div>
        <div class="overlay">
          <h2 class="card-title title"></h2>
          <div class="more">
            <a href="post.html">
              <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> More </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card card-pin">
        <img class="card-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.jpg?text=irtiza" alt="#1546">
        <div class="text-block">
        </div>
        <div class="overlay">
          <h2 class="card-title title"></h2>
          <div class="more">
            <a href="post.html">
              <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> More </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The only change you need to update your css,    `-webkit-column-count: 10;` in all where you use column count.
thanks

Comment: that does not work for me. It still shows only 6, but with smaller pictures

Comment: try my above code css